# Select top ties in SQL Server doesn't return expected data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `NdtReports` with this data:

[image]

Another table called `ndtreportdetails` with this data:

[image]

These two tables are joined based on `ndtreportdetails.reportid` and `Report.id`

I execute this query :

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    NRD.NdtType, NRD.RequestNumber, NR.NdtReportNumber,
    NRD.ResponseReportDatetime, NRD.Defect,
    NRD.ResponseReportNumber, NRD.Remark
FROM   
    dbo.NdtReportDetails NRD
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    NdtReports NR ON NRD.ReportId = NR.Id
WHERE  
    NRD.JointId = 1661632
    AND NRD.NdtType IN ('RT', 'PT', 'PWHT', 'MT', 'UT')
ORDER BY 
    NRD.Id DESC
```

It returns this result:

[image]

It returns the last recorded of the jointid with maximum id, but I need the last record with maximum id for all types `RT,PT,UT`. The expected result should be 3 records with id 139189 (PT), 139193 (UT), 139192 (RT)

Text data :
report:

```
Id  NdtReportNumber NdtReportDate   UserId  SubmitDateTime  Type
6292    IR-AFP-AG-PT-0001   2017-01-07 09:15:13.937 59  2017-01-07 09:15:13.917 PT
6293    IR-AFP-AG-RT-0001   2017-01-07 09:20:54.397 59  2017-01-07 09:20:54.367 UT
6294    IR-AFP-AG-RT-0001   2017-01-07 09:23:15.513 59  2017-01-07 09:23:15.487 RT
6295    IR-AFP-AG-RT-000    2017-01-07 09:41:21.807 59  2017-01-07 09:41:21.787 RT
6296    IR-AFP-AG-RT-000    2017-01-07 09:42:45.427 59  2017-01-07 09:42:45.400 UT
```

NDTreportdetail

```
Id  ReportId    State   Defect  SubmitDateTime  NdtType ResponseReportNumber    ResponseReportDatetime  Remark  JointId RequestNumber   RequestDatetime
139189  6292            2017-01-07 09:15:37.207 PT  pt psa res  2017-01-07 09:15:13.957     1661632 pt psa  NULL
139190  6293            2017-01-07 09:21:14.853 UT  ut result psa   2017-01-07 09:20:54.440     1661632 ut psa  NULL
139191  6294            2017-01-07 09:23:29.473 RT  dsad    2017-01-07 09:23:15.530     1661632 adasa   NULL
139192  6295    NULL        2017-01-07 09:41:21.820 RT  NULL    2017-01-07 09:41:21.820 NULL    1661632 NULL    NULL
139193  6296    NULL        2017-01-07 09:42:45.437 UT  NULL    2017-01-07 09:42:45.437 NULL    1661632 NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I had a mistake in the id number i updated them :the expected id number :139189(PT),139193(UT),139192(RT)

Comment: @GurV i will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.NdtType,
       t.RequestNumber,
       t.NdtReportNumber,
       t.ResponseReportDatetime,
       t.Defect,
       t.ResponseReportNumber,
       t.Remark
FROM
(
    SELECT NRD.NdtType,
           NRD.Id,
           NRD.RequestNumber,
           NR.NdtReportNumber,
           NRD.ResponseReportDatetime,
           NRD.Defect,
           NRD.ResponseReportNumber,
           NRD.Remark,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NRD.NdtType ORDER BY NRD.Id DESC) AS rn
    FROM dbo.NdtReportDetails NRD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN NdtReports NR
        ON NRD.ReportId = NR.Id
    WHERE NRD.JointId = 1661632 AND
          NRD.NdtType IN ('RT', 'PT', 'PWHT', 'MT', 'UT')
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.Id DESC
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Your query returns the false data for rt record:RT 139191 adasa IR-AFP-AG-RT-0001 2017-01-07 09:23:15.530  dsad  1

Comment: It should be 139192

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NRD.NdtType ORDER BY NRD.Id DESC) AS rn` ... kindly let me know if this partition looks correct to you.  Your question is not the clearest one I have seen on this site.

Comment: My friend your query just is a part of main query ,so i added your query to my mani query but i  get this error :) ) Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SPJointHistory, Line 72
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518849/sql-the-order-by-clause-is-invalid-in-views-inline-functions-derived-tables-s

Comment: Please help my application now is running in my customer company and because of this problem returns incorrect result to my users