# SQL Server : the ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I have this query in a stored procedure):

```
SELECT *
FROM   
    dbo.JointHistory c
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT 
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterRTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorRTReportNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS RTDate,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Defect END) AS RTDefect,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Remark END) AS RTSegment,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterPTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorPTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorPTReportNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PTDate,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Defect END) AS PTDefect,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Remark END) AS PTSegment,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterPWHTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorPWHTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorPWHTReportNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PWHTDate,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN Defect END) AS PWHTDefect,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN Remark END) AS PWHTSegment,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterMTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorMTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorMTReportNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS MTDate,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN Defect END) AS MTDefect,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN Remark END) AS MTSegment,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterUTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorUTRequestNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorUTReportNumber,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS UTDate,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN Defect END) AS UTDefect,
         MAX(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN Remark END) AS UTSegment
     FROM   
         (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
              NRD.NdtType, NRD.RequestNumber, NR.NdtReportNumber,
              NRD.ResponseReportDatetime, NRD.Defect,
              NRD.ResponseReportNumber, NRD.Remark
          FROM   
              dbo.NdtReportDetails NRD
          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              NdtReports NR ON NRD.ReportId = NR.Id
          WHERE  
              NRD.JointId = c.Id
              AND NRD.NdtType IN ( 'RT', 'PT', 'PWHT', 'MT', 'UT' )
          ORDER BY 
              NRD.Id DESC) i) b
```

But the end of query had a problem based on this question [:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518618/select-top-ties-in-sql-cant-return-expected-data/41518699](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518618/select-top-ties-in-sql-cant-return-expected-data/41518699)

So my query is changed to this :

```
 SELECT *
FROM   dbo.JointHistory c
       OUTER Apply (SELECT Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorRTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS RTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Defect END) AS RTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Remark END) AS RTSegment,

                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterPTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorPTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorPTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Defect END) AS PTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Remark END) AS PTSegment,

                               Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterPWHTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorPWHTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorPWHTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PWHTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN Defect END) AS PWHTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN Remark END) AS PWHTSegment,

                                   Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterMTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorMTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorMTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS MTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN Defect END) AS MTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN Remark END) AS MTSegment,

                                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterUTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorUTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorUTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS UTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN Defect END) AS UTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN Remark END) AS UTSegment


                    FROM   (

SELECT t.NdtType,
       t.RequestNumber,
       t.NdtReportNumber,
       t.ResponseReportDatetime,
       t.Defect,
       t.ResponseReportNumber,
       t.Remark
FROM
(
    SELECT NRD.NdtType,
           NRD.Id,
           NRD.RequestNumber,
           NR.NdtReportNumber,
           NRD.ResponseReportDatetime,
           NRD.Defect,
           NRD.ResponseReportNumber,
           NRD.Remark,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NRD.NdtType ORDER BY NRD.Id DESC) AS rn
    FROM dbo.NdtReportDetails NRD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN NdtReports NR
        ON NRD.ReportId = NR.Id
    WHERE NRD.JointId = c.Id AND
          NRD.NdtType IN ('RT', 'PT', 'PWHT', 'MT', 'UT')
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY t.Id DESC

) i)b
```

As you can see the end of query is changed based on above question, after I execute this query, I get this error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SPJointHistory, Line 72
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Try moving the `ORDER BY` to the OUTER select. If you think about it, it makes no sense to have an `order by` in an inner select since the wrapping one does not necessarily honors the order of the received results set.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. What part of it are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: @KenWhite i don't know what should i do exactly

Comment: Remove the ORDER BY from the subquery, which is precisely what the error message tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you have an `ORDER BY` in the inner query.Since you are not displaying the `id` I don't think ordering it by id makes any sense. So you can remove the order by and convert the INNER Query to a `CTE` and do it like this:

```
;WITH ReportTable
AS(
   SELECT t.NdtType,
       t.RequestNumber,
       t.NdtReportNumber,
       t.ResponseReportDatetime,
       t.Defect,
       t.ResponseReportNumber,
       t.Remark
FROM
(
    SELECT NRD.NdtType,
           NRD.Id,
           NRD.RequestNumber,
           NR.NdtReportNumber,
           NRD.ResponseReportDatetime,
           NRD.Defect,
           NRD.ResponseReportNumber,
           NRD.Remark,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NRD.NdtType ORDER BY NRD.Id DESC) AS rn
    FROM dbo.NdtReportDetails NRD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN NdtReports NR
        ON NRD.ReportId = NR.Id
    WHERE NRD.JointId = c.Id AND
          NRD.NdtType IN ('RT', 'PT', 'PWHT', 'MT', 'UT')
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
)


SELECT *
FROM   dbo.JointHistory c
       OUTER Apply (SELECT Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorRTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorRTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS RTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Defect END) AS RTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'RT' THEN Remark END) AS RTSegment,

                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterPTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorPTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorPTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Defect END) AS PTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PT' THEN Remark END) AS PTSegment,

                               Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterPWHTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorPWHTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorPWHTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS PWHTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN Defect END) AS PWHTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'PWHT' THEN Remark END) AS PWHTSegment,

                                   Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterMTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorMTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorMTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS MTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN Defect END) AS MTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'MT' THEN Remark END) AS MTSegment,

                                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN RequestNumber END) AS MasterUTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN NdtReportNumber END) AS ContractorUTRequestNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN ResponseReportNumber END) AS ContractorUTReportNumber,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN ResponseReportDatetime END) AS UTDate,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN Defect END) AS UTDefect,
                           Max(CASE NdtType WHEN 'UT' THEN Remark END) AS UTSegment
                     FROM  ReportTable  i)b
--ORDER BY b.Id DESC
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
Invalid column name 'Id'.

Comment: Maybe consider using a CTE here, which would also make things easier to read.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar On what you want to order the final result set? `NdtReportDetails` table's `Id` ??

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Changed to `CTE` instead of multiple INNER Query.